# How to implement session time out in Django login form using Django and Python

Tags: python, django, session

I need to implement the session time out functionality in inbuilt Django form. Here I need to save time in session and will check in each page. If the expired time is out then again the it will return to login page. I am providing my code below.

```
class Signup(View):

    """ this class is used for user signup """

    def get(self, request):
        """ this function used to get the sign up form """
        form = UserCreationForm()
        return render(request, 'booking/signup.html', {'form': form})

    def post(self, request):
        """ this function used for post the sign up data """
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('login')


class AuthLogin(View):

    """ Its for login """

    def get(self, request):
        """ this function used to get the login form """
        form = AuthenticationForm()
        return render(request, 'booking/login.html', {'form': form})

    def post(self, request):
        """ this function used for post the login data """
        form = AuthenticationForm(None, request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            login(request, form.get_user())
        return redirect('/')


def home(request):
    """ This is for displaying the home page """
    return render(request, 'booking/home.html', {})
```

My requirement is when user will logged in the current time will store in session and it will check in home page, here the session should live up to 10min after login if there is no activity then the time will out and return to login page.

Comment: Django already has a setting to let you configure how long a session should last (`SESSION_COOKIE_AGE`) - why don't you just set that to 10 minutes?

Comment: Actually I am new to Django first time getting some confusion about how to set and check for all pages.

Comment: @satya This link may help you https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#std:setting-SESSION_COOKIE_AGE